# What is the meaning behind "Congratulations, I hope you have a wonderful life together"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

This isn't about a glitch or bug, I really just want to know the meaning of [Constance's](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Constance_Michel) over-used term, "Congratulations, I hope you have a wonderful life together." Does it mean anything? I'm not married in the game and haven't adopted children from her.

Comment: Define over-used.  From what I gather, [*this is a bug*](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:832262), unless you are able to have other dialogue from her as well.

Comment: I guess it is a bug? I haven't been able to adopt children from her. It's all she says so I thought it meant something.

Answer (score 2):

That is her quote for when you adopt a child.When i got a child she said "congragulations, i hope you have a wonderful life together" which indicates you adopted a child.This is more likely a bug for this can also happen to different npc's repeating the exact same quote over and over.

Comment: inb4 "arrow in the knee" jokes.